# Initializing "intent.extras" with a null variable declared as "Bundle" object

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, bundle, crash

There is a type mismatch when initializing `b` as `intent.extra`. Though `b` is of type `Bundle?` and `intent.extra` doesn't take `null` values and also `Bundle` can't be null.

Please suggest a solution for this issue. The app keeps on crashing when installed on an android phone and ready to run.

The following code snippet present in the code body is showing only warning but ends up in application crash on start only.

```
    import android.app.Activity
    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.graphics.Bitmap
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.provider.MediaStore
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.view.Menu
    import android.view.MenuItem
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter
    import android.widget.Toast
    import com.example.debo.kickv01.R.id.lvTweets
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_navig.*
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.app_bar_navig.*

    import com.example.debo.kickv01.saved
    import com.example.debo.kickv01.login as lg
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
    import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_saved.view.*
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
    import java.util.*

    class navig : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth?=null
        private var database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        private var myRef = database.reference

        var list_T=ArrayList<ticket>()
        var adaptor:MyPrjAdaptor?=null
        var UserUID:String?=null
        var myEmail:String?=null
        // var b:Bundle= intent.extras
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_navig)
            val toolbar= null
            var b:Bundle = intent.extras
            myEmail = b.getString("email")
            UserUID = b.getString("uid")

            list_T.add(ticket("0","him","url","add"))
            list_T.add(ticket("0","him","url","debo"))
            list_T.add(ticket("0","him","url","debo_2"))

            adaptor=MyPrjAdaptor(this,list_T)
            lvTweets.adapter=adaptor

            fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show()
            }

            val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
            drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
            toggle.syncState()

            nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        }

        override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_home -> {
                    // Handle the camera action
                    var intent = Intent(this, navig::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.nav_explore -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, explore::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.nav_Saved -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, saved::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.nav_actions -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, actions::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.nav_login -> {
                    var intent = Intent(this, com.example.debo.kickv01.login::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }

            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            return true
        }

        inner class MyPrjAdaptor: BaseAdapter{
            var listNotesAdaptor= ArrayList<ticket>()
            var context:Context?=null
            constructor(context: Context,listNotesAdaptor: ArrayList<ticket>):super(){
                this.listNotesAdaptor=listNotesAdaptor
                this.context=context
            }

            override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
                var myTweet=listNotesAdaptor[position]

                if (myTweet.tweetPersonUID.equals("add")) {
                    var myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_saved, null)
                    myView.etAttach.setOnClickListener {
                        loadImage()
                    }

                    myView.etPost.setOnClickListener {
                        myRef.child("posts").push().setValue(PostInfo(UserUID!!,
                                myView.etProject.text.toString(),
                                myView.etDescription.text.toString(),
                                DownloadURL!!))

                    }
                    return myView
                }else{
                    var myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_explore, null)
                    return myView
                }
            }

            override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
                return listNotesAdaptor[position]
            }

            override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
                return position.toLong()
            }

            override fun getCount(): Int {
                return listNotesAdaptor.size
            }
        }

        override fun onBackPressed() {
            if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
        }

        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.navig, menu)
            return true
        }

        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.action_settings -> return true
                else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
            }
        }

        var PICK_IMAGE_CODE=123
        fun loadImage(){
            var intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_CODE)
        }

        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

            if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_CODE && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK && data!=null){
                val selectedImage=data.data
                val filePathColum = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                val cursor= contentResolver.query(selectedImage,filePathColum,null,null,null)
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                val columIndex= cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColum[0])
                val picturepath= cursor.getString(columIndex)
                cursor.close()
                UploadImage(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturepath))
            }
        }

        var DownloadURL:String?=null
        fun UploadImage(bitmap: Bitmap){
            var currentUser= mAuth!!.currentUser

            val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
            val storageRef= storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://kick-13840.appspot.com")
            val df= SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss")
            val dataobj= Date()
            val imagePath= SplitString(myEmail!!) + "."+ df.format(dataobj)+ ".jpg"
            val ImageRef= storageRef.child("imagePost/"+imagePath)


            val baos= ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos)
            val data=baos.toByteArray()
            val uploadTask=ImageRef.putBytes(data)
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"fail to upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                DownloadURL = taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl.toString()
            }
        }

        fun SplitString(email: String):String{
            val split= email.split("@")
            return split[0]
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `private val bundle by lazy { intent.extras }`?

Comment: what is the error or Issue ?

Comment: How this value 'bundle' is going to help is getting variable 'b' a non null object. @EpicPandaForce

Comment: oh I just renamed `b` to `bundle` because good coding practices include "not using single-letter variable names" (most of the time).

Comment: issue is 'intent.extras' don't take null values and as 'b' is 'Bundle?' object 'intent.extras' is showing hint as "Type mismatch. Required:Bundle Found:Bundle?" -@AbhayKoradiya

Comment: it is showing error message as " Missing 'setValue(navig, KProperty<*>, Bundle!)' method on delegate of type 'Lazy<Bundle!>'"  Also i need bundle as a var   @EpicPandaForce

Comment: You don't need it as a `var`, that just means your logic is wrong.

Comment: Post your error stack please.

Answer (score 0):

b is of type `Bundle` whereas intent.extras returns `Bundle?` (`Intent.getExtras()` is annotated with `@Nullable` if you look at the code for it) as indicated by the IDE. You need to either use the not-null assertion operator, !!, or change b to type `Bundle?`.